# Open second activity on menu item click

Tags: java, android, android-activity, menu

I have been looking for a way to open a secondary activity from a menu item click. After several different attempts to find an answer to my question in other people's posts, I decided to ask a question. Help would be much appreciated in the form of code snippets to apply quickly, thank you :)

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        //open gallery
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PhotoGallery.class));
    }

    else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_msg)
    {
        MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: For clarification: by activity - do you mean an anctivity or a fragment? fby 'menu' you mean a navigation drawer?

Comment: In this, I made some poor word choices. I do mean activity, and I actually meant navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        //open gallery

        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, PhotoActivity.class);
        //if you need to pass data: 
        Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
        mBundle.putString("myKey", "opengalleryclicked");
        galleryIntent.putExtras(mBundle); 
        startActivity(galleryIntent);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Data passed can be received in your second activity by:

```
String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("myKey");
```